# Django get the list of checked checkbox from html and process in views.py

Tags: django

I have a checkbox in template and want to get the lit of value from checked checkbox for rendering to pdf in views.py. Do I need to create a form for it? No idea how to combine it.

html:

```
{% for order in orders %}
 <div class="mb-3">
      {% for item in order.items.all %}
                <input type="checkbox" name="item_checkbox" value="{{ item.item.id }}" >{{ item.item.product_name }}<br>
      {% endfor %}
</div>

<a href="{% url 'generate_pdf' id=order.id %}" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">PDF</a>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I get the checkbox value and pass it to views.py?

pdf rendering in views.py

```
def generate_to_pdf(request, id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=id)
    time_now = timezone.now()
    template = get_template('invoice.html')
    context = {
        'order': order,
        'time_now': time_now
    }
    template.render(context)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('invoice.html', context)
    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Should I do the Form post method in below funcion for get the value from html?

views.py for the above html:

```
def order_admin(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    context = {
        'orders': orders,
    }
    return render(request, 'product_admin.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of selected checkbox values from POST request like

```py
checked_items = request.POST.getlist("item_checkbox")
```

`checked_items` will be a list of ids of items which were checked.

Make a form with `action="{% url 'generate_pdf' id=order.id %}"`

In view function `generate_to_pdf`

```py
def generate_to_pdf(request, id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=id)
    checked_items = request.POST.getlist("item_checkbox") # get checked values
    time_now = timezone.now()
    template = get_template('invoice.html')
    # remaining code
```